# PHPExcel, Копирование листа из одного документа xls в другой с сохранением оформления

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xls

Мне необходимо составить xls-файл, используя листы из других файлов.

Делаю примерно так:

```
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
        $file_tmpl = $objReader->load('doc10.xls');
```

$file_tmpl - результирующий файл

```
        $file1 = $objReader->load('doc11.xls');
```

$file1 - файл, из которого копируется лист

```
        $file1->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
        $sheet = $file1->getActiveSheet();          
        $file_tmpl->addSheet($sheet,1);
```

В результате лист копируется, за исключением оформления ячеек: границы, шрифты, размер текста, цвет текста.
Как перенести всё вместе с оформлением?

Answer (score 1):

проблема решилась использованием

```
    $file_tmpl->addExternalSheet($sheet);
```

вместо

```
    $file_tmpl->addSheet($sheet,1);
```